# How to update claim in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have ASP.NET Core application with IdentityServer4 using ASP.NET Core Identity (based on excellent [quickstart](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html)). What I can't find is how should I *update* the claim. For example, my business application wants to change `given_name` or custom claim like `passport`. When I initialized the values in Core Identity store, I used `UserManager.AddClaimAsync()`, but obviously that is the wrong approach during operations. And if I just call `User.Identity.AddClaim()` - it doesn't persist (which is not surprising).

But how to modify Claims from Core application? Any documentation that I missed?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking. Are you trying to update and persist the claim? As in update user information?

Comment: yes. with the wrinkle that there is a business Web application that successfully retrieves claims from IdentityServer4; and I would think that Web App makes some call (through IdentityModel, perhaps? Or directly some POST call?) to IdentityServer that updates user info.

Comment: Ill start off by saying i havent used identityserver 4 in any length at all. But are you asking for how to perform CRUD operations in asp net core? If so i find that the default project template in Visual Studio is a good source for that.

If you mean specifically modify claims then UserManager is a good bet. It has multiple operations regarding claims. Or just use EntityFramework to modify them as you see fit.

In practise: Retrieve the claim from database, edit it, SaveChanges().

Answer (score -1):

You can add, change the claims by implementing the IProfileService interface in IdentityServer4